State Discrimination with Scattering and Lorentz Force
Assume I have an atom that has spin aligned on the x axis (+x or -x) or on the z axis (+z or -z), but I don't know which of these options, only that it is one of these options. I need to find out only in which direction the spin is (parallel to the x or z axis) and not in which exactly. This is a state discrimination problem, and since there are four possible states and they are not orthogonal to each other, I think it should be impossible to even tell parallel to which axis it is.
However, I was thinking that if an electron with spin +x was moving close to this atom, parallel to the x axis, if the atom's spin was also parallel to this axis, there would be no Lorentz force, while if the spin was parallel to the z axis, there would be.
However, if the electron's spin were +x and the atom's -x, there would be scattering, while if both were +x, there would be none. If the atom's spin were on the z axis, there would be a probability of scattering.
So, in short, if the spins of the electron and the atom were +x, there would be no Lorentz force or scattering. If they were opposite +x and -x, there would be no Lorentz force but there would be scattering. If they were in combinations of x and z, there could be both, both scattering and Lorentz Force, and in that case I imagine that the electron would be detected in positions that would not occur otherwise.
Therefore, looking at these positions, I would know that the atom has spin on the z axis (+z or -z), because only then would the electron stop where it stopped. However, I believe that this is wrong, because it contradicts many things that are seen in Quantum Information Theory.
